# What is wrong with this PowerShell script? (trying to create username and settings remotely)

Tags: powershell, remote

I've got the following PowerShell script and it doesn't seem to work, it seems to throw an error when you get to line 21 (else).

```
$Username = "asdfasdfasdf"
$Password = "asdfasdfasdfasdf"

$group = "Administrators"

$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$existing = $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.Name -eq $Username }

if ($existing -eq $null) {

    Write-Host "Creating new local user $Username."
    & NET USER $Username $Password /add /y /expires:never

   Write-Host "Adding local user $Username to $group."
   & NET LOCALGROUP $group $Username /add

}
else {
    Write-Host "Setting password for existing local user $Username."
    $existing.SetPassword($Password)
}

 Write-Host "Ensuring password for $Username never expires."
 & WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='$Username'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

Error message:

```
else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ else {
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: When you debug the script, what are the values of each of your variables, and what error do you receive?  Instead of submitting a temporary comment, you should edit your question.

Comment: please, add the error text to your Question. PoSh usually includes some useful info with the full text of an error msg.

Comment: also, why have you set the `remote` tag? i don't see any remote calls ...

Comment: last of all ... why don't you use the powershell cmdlets for this? you are calling `net.exe` and `wmic.exe` ... and there are PoSh cmdlets for both of those.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Please edit, or copy/paste a previous comment into a new one, deleting the old, if no one has commented after you in lieu of multiple one sentence comments.

Comment: @JW0914 - they seem to be different points and would be best answered individually. however, if splatting them all in one comment is policy ... i will do so in the future.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey You can ask multiple questions in a single comment. Posting multiple comments when the characters haven't went beyond the limit is inefficient, needlessly causing a longer comment thread than necessary

Comment: Please confirm if you are running the whole script at once? (Running it line by line / sections could result in this behaviour.) Also please check that there is not other characters (Visible or not) between the closing `}` of the `if` statement and the start of the `else` statement (could be a hidden character triggering it if copied from an online source).

Comment: @CraftyB Actually I think it was running line by line. How would I make sure it's running all at once instead?

Comment: @JW0914 - i will keep that in mind. thank you for the feedback! [*grin*]

Comment: @logan86 - If you are using PowerShell ISE you can use F5 to execute the whole script, or F8 to run highlighted text. Please advise what you are using to edit the script?

Comment: @CraftyB Thank you it sounds like that will help, so far I've only been editing it in Notepad++ and then I had just copied/pasted that into a regular PowerShell window. I will try PowerShell ISE now and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a script line by line or by sections can sometimes cause undesired effects.

`Else` statements are not valid unless executed in the same instance as the `if` statement.

If executing scripts in sections you must include all `if`,`else`,`elseif` statements if they exist in the section that you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was because of using right click paste in PowerShell so it was running it one single line at a time. By running it all at once (e.g as a script, PowerShell ISE, or by simply using Ctrl+V to paste before executing then it works fine. Thank you to everyone for your help.